# Android - setFocusedMonthDateColor() and setUnfocusedMonthDateColor() are depricated in SDK level 23

Tags: android, deprecated, calendarview

`setFocusedMonthDateColor()` and `setUnfocusedMonthDateColor()` are depricated from SDK level 23 onward and here is the what Android Docs has to say about the attribute [`focusedMonthDateColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#focusedMonthDateColor):

> May be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or
>   "#aarrggbb".
>
> Constant Value: 16843587 (0x01010343)

What does that even mean? And how am I supposed to color the focused and unfocused months of `CalendarView`?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of methods in `CalendarView` have been deprecated in API 23. All of them show:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23.
>
> No longer used by Material-style CalendarView.

It seems to me that those methods are mostly meant for customizing the colors of the view. And I therfore think (read: don't know exactly) that they want you to use the - in Android 5 introduced - `colorPrimary` etc. items. For example, a selected month would probably get the `colorAccent`.

Give it a try.

Comment: I already have the `colorAccent` in my `style.xml`. But it is not receiving colors from it. It is using the by-default colors, which in my case are not a problem, but it could be for some one else.

Comment: So how do we style the CalendarView then? I'm not finding anything except "Everything is deprecated."